# Connect to AKS with authorized IP using Github Actions

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, azure-aks, continuous-deployment

My AKS cluster has an authorized IP. I am trying to deploy a Github Actions workflow to the AKS but the connection is refused because of the IP range. Any ideas? What's the best way to handle this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Please take a look at the following link for some tips on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you could use a selft-hoster runner inside your VNET: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners.